# Logic: excluded_middle_irrefutable

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Here is the task from the book:

> Proving the consistency of Coq with the general excluded middle axiom
>   requires complicated reasoning that cannot be carried out within Coq
>   itself.  However, the following theorem implies that it is always safe
>   to assume a decidability axiom (i.e., an instance of excluded middle)
>   for any *particular* Prop [P].  Why?  Because we cannot prove the
>   negation of such an axiom.  If we could, we would have both [~ (P /
>   ~P)] and [~ ~ (P / ~P)] (since [P] implies [~ ~ P], by the exercise
>   below), which would be a contradiction.  But since we can't, it is
>   safe to add [P / ~P] as an axiom.

As far as I understand the task, I must introduce excluded middle Axiom.
But I am not sure that I did it correctly:

```
Axiom decidability : forall (P:Prop),
    (P \/ ~ P) = True.

(* Theorem double_neg : ∀P : Prop,
       P → ~~P. *)

Theorem excluded_middle_irrefutable: forall (P:Prop),
  ~ ~ (P \/ ~ P).
Proof.
  intros P. apply double_neg.
```

Now we got `(P \/ ~ P)`, but when I try `apply decidability.`, it gives an error:

```
Unable to unify "(?M1052 \/ ~ ?M1052) = True" with "P \/ ~ P".
```

What to do?

Comment: `rewrite decidability. constructor.` will do, though it's not how you're supposed to solve the task (as pointed out in the answer).

Comment: @Bubbler constructor tactic is not introduced in the book at this point. How do they suppose me to know it?

Comment: That `constructor` is there to prove `True`. Since `I` is the constructor of type `True`, `apply I.` does the same job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is asking you to prove `excluded_middle_irrefutable` without assuming *any* axioms.

Comment: In this case why do they say about assuming an axiom: "the following theorem implies that it is always safe to assume a decidability axiom (i.e., an instance of excluded middle) for any particular Prop"?

Comment: @user4035 Your understanding of cause and effect is reversed. You should first prove `~~(P \/ ~P)` in Coq's logic without introducing the axiom, and *then* it is guaranteed to be safe to use the axiom when proving *other* theorems. (Side remark: For any statement X, if you write `~~X` and prove it, it is equivalent to saying "X is consistent with Coq's logic, so it is safe to add as an axiom.")

Comment: @Bubbler not "equivalent to saying", right? You cannot prove `~~excluded_middle`, but it is safe to add it as an axiom

Comment: I guess it should've been "implies" instead of "equivalent". Or should I mention that universal quantifiers should go before double negation?